# Logging in with Facebook using Flask-Stormpath on PythonAnywhere raises JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, facebook, flask, pythonanywhere, stormpath

I am trying to deploy my application on PythonAnywhere but I am unable to set up the Flask-Stormpath Facebook login.

The email based login and Google connect are working fine, but Facebook login is not working. I have updated the Facebook app to the correct application url and verified that Facebook connect does work on localhost.

```
2016-04-14 18:08:07,121 :Exception on /facebook [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/btpraasta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_stormpath/views.py", line 265, in facebook_login
    current_app.config['STORMPATH_SOCIAL']['FACEBOOK']['app_secret'],
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/facebook.py", line 497, in get_user_from_cookie
    app_id, app_secret)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/facebook.py", line 581, in get_access_token_from_code
    response = json.loads(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 488, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 389, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Here are the configuration for StormPath that I am using :-

```
# Stormpath app configuration
app.config['STORMPATH_API_KEY_FILE'] = '/home/btpraasta/btp_raasta/stormpath/apiKey.properties'
app.config['STORMPATH_API_KEY_FILE'] = 'stormpath/apiKey.properties'
app.config['STORMPATH_APPLICATION'] = 'Raasta'
app.config['STORMPATH_REDIRECT_URL'] = '/redirecting'
app.config['STORMPATH_REGISTRATION_REDIRECT_URL'] = '/verifyEmail'
app.config['STORMPATH_REGISTRATION_TEMPLATE'] = 'register.html'
app.config['STORMPATH_LOGIN_TEMPLATE'] = 'login.html'
app.config['STORMPATH_FORGOT_PASSWORD_TEMPLATE'] = 'forgot.html'
app.config['STORMPATH_ENABLE_MIDDLE_NAME'] = False
app.config['STORMPATH_ENABLE_USERNAME'] = True
app.config['STORMPATH_REQUIRE_USERNAME'] = True
app.config['STORMPATH_ENABLE_FORGOT_PASSWORD'] = True
app.config['STORMPATH_ENABLE_FACEBOOK'] = True
app.config['STORMPATH_ENABLE_GOOGLE'] = True
app.config['STORMPATH_SOCIAL'] = {
    'FACEBOOK': {
        'app_id': 'xxxxx',
        'app_secret': 'xxxxx',
    },
    'GOOGLE': {
        'client_id': 'xxxxx',
        'client_secret': 'xxxxxx',
    }
}
```

The client_id and client_secret have been hidden. The same configuration does work on the localhost.

Comment: That error looks like some of the data being sent isn't valid. I'm the author of this library -- can you also include your configuration data for everything?

Comment: @rdegges I have added the configuration details. PythonAnywhere uses a proxy to allow free accounts to connect to the web. Is there any possibility that might be the reason?

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- you're right about the proxy.  It may be that the code is correctly connecting to the proxy, but the site that you're trying to access is not on our whitelist of sites that free accounts can access.  If it's a publicly-accessible API we can probably add it -- just send us a feedback message on the site with the API endpoint and a link to the docs.

Comment: @GilesThomas The code is part of an extension and not exactly an API. The extension is able to do google login and connect with its cloud database for email based logins, so I do not think that the issue might be due to the site not being white-listed. It maybe possible that some intermediate connection is happening which might not be white-listed leading to the error.

Comment: @rdegges Can you please have a look at it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was due to Facebook-SDK version 0.4 which did not have output proxy support. Raised a ticked and now Flask-Stormpath uses Facebook-SDK version 1.0 which supports the same.

If you still face the same issue update your Flask-Stormpath :-

```
pip install --upgrade flask-stormpath
```